# Magento 2 : How to call static block in category

Tags: magento2

In magento 1.9, I can call easily static block in category by assigning the **`Display mode`** to `static block` and select the `cms block`.

But i want to do it in magento2 also. I am doing same but not getting the `cms block content.`

I have cleaned the `cache` and also run following command

1. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Let me know what i am doing wrong.

Note : I am using custom theme. It is coming on default luma theme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have checked in my magento 2 setup as you say.. but it works as same as before...

Comment: This does not work with Magento 2.1.5 and Luma. Just set category to show both products and static block and then set a static block for the category and no static block content is shown at category page even after cache flushing and deploying static content.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in M 2.1.3 EE edition :( . It sucks

Comment: I have upgraded my magento 2.1 to 2.2 and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Let’s say, you want to add a static block to Home > Women > Tops
>   category:
>
> 2) In the admin panel, you need to navigate to the category in question.
>   Open your admin panel and go to Product => Categories.
>
> 3) Then find the Women > Tops category.
>
> 4) Then open the Content tab.
>
> 5) There you will see Add CMS Block section. Here you can select the
>   static block you would like to display (I selected “Sale Left Menu
>   Block”).
>
> 6) Then in the Display Settings tab find Display Mode and choose the
>   necessary mode. In my case, it’s “Static block and products”.
>
> 7) Don’t forget to press “Save” button.
>
> 8) Now you can check the results on the Category page by do clean cache.
>
> Please comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1]** Create a custom block

**Step 2]** Go to category form
   there you can see ***Content*** tab

> you will see an option **Add CMS Block** : you can chose your custom cms block

**Step 3]** go to ***display setting*** tab

> Change the display mode to : **static block and products**

Then go to frontend category page you can see the Static CMS page Content and products

This works for me, If you have any query let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First of all You have to go Categories and go to display setting and select Display Mode to Static Blocks only or Static Block or Products https://prnt.sc/h47f13 
then Goto Content And Select Add CMS Block to select you want to insert in Category https://prnt.sc/h47flb

Then Save Category and do not forget to Clear Cache.

Please let me know if other question.

Thanks